# Configure M1 VSCode ARM but with a rosetta terminal

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I am on m1 arm chip. I would like VSCode to run on ARM but I would like the vscode terminal itself to run in rosetta. How can I do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### How to run using Rosetta from the command line

In general, you can use the `arch` command to run a program using Rosetta like this:

```
/usr/bin/arch -arch x86_64 program args...
```

So you can run an instance of `zsh` using Rosetta like this:

```
/usr/bin/arch -arch x86_64 /bin/zsh
```

And that shell will run all subprocesses using Rosetta as well (unless one of them uses `arch` to switch back to `arm64`…).

### How to set up a Visual Studio Code Terminal profile to use Rosetta

Open your `settings.json` file. In Code you can open `settings.json` from the menu bar by choosing View > Command Palette, typing `open settings json` into the palette text field, and then choosing “Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)” from the palette list.

Here's my `settings.json` with a Terminal profile added to run `zsh` under Rosetta:

```json
{
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "haskell.plugin.hlint.codeActionsOn": false,
    "haskell.plugin.hlint.diagnosticsOn": false,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "x86 zsh": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/arch",
            "args": ["-arch", "x86_64", "/bin/zsh"]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "x86 zsh"
}
```

So copy the `terminal.integrated.profiless.osx` clause from that example into your own `settings.json` and edit it to your taste. Also copy the `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx` setting if you want the Rosetta `zsh` to be your default Terminal profile.

If you don't use `x86 zsh` as your default Terminal profile, then you have to start it manually by using the pull-down menu attached to the + button in the Terminal pane:

[image: new Terminal pull-down menu with x86 zsh item highlighted]

Comment: Thank you!  I don't use VSCode, but I had set up an x86_64 Terminal profile over a year ago, forgot how it worked, and accidentally deleted the command when I wanted to switch back to ARM.  I tried to search for it again, and found so many convoluted answers which I knew were wrong.  This is truly the simplest way to allow switching back and forth between platforms in Terminal.

Comment: To avoid confusion and to be sure you are really using `x86 zsh` instead of default `zsh`, you can also add `"overrideName": true` allows for setting own profile name under `"x86 zsh"` so that the profile name appears as `x86 zsh` instead of default `zsh`

Answer (score 0):

I see the best option to use Rosetta settings on VS code is to download the Intel version from [official website](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download). This will by default run in `i386` arch as expected.
For arch `arm64` you can use either the Universal version or the Apple Silicon one.

[image]

Comment: VSCode for Macs are Universal builds now, that run on both Intel and Apple silicon MACS. Moreover, I have seen that running x86 applications are often quite resource intensive (CPU and Battery). It's much more efficient to setup a separate Terminal profile in your VSCode, or other IDEs like PyCharm.